# Lotus Notes Webservice consumer

Tags: xml, web-services, character-encoding, lotusscript

Im having some trouble with a Lotus Notes Webservice consumer (Lotus Script).
It's supposed to send a parameter (string) and recieve a list.
This works fine, but when I try to send a slash character "/" then it fails.

My program looks like this.

```
'** Notes declarations:
Dim ws                                      As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim session                                 As New NotesSession
Dim uidoc                                   As NotesUIDocument
Dim db                                      As NotesDatabase
Dim doc                                     As NotesDocument
Dim listfield                               As NotesItem
Dim dok                                     As NotesDocument    
Dim view                                    As Notesview
Dim NotesDocumentCollection     As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim item                                    As NotesItem
Dim notesItem                           As NotesItem

Dim LA_ReturnArray  As New ArrayOfString_n3()
Dim LA_string           As New ArrayOfString_n3()
Dim Engaku              As New Engaku()

Dim LV_variant          As Variant
Dim LS_searchString As String 
Dim Intermediate        As XSD_STRING
Dim i                       As Integer
Dim L                       As Integer
Dim m                       As Integer
Dim n                       As Integer

Dim LS_SearchValue As String 
Dim LS_ReplacementValue As String


Set uidoc   = ws.CurrentDocument
Set doc         = uidoc.Document
Set db      = Session.CurrentDatabase

LS_searchString = "address road 1/d"

LV_variant = Engaku.getCustomerNames( LS_searchString )
```

Is there a way to handle sending a slash "/"

Comment: Did you try sending the slash encoded? Like %2F?

Comment: @Michael Ruhnau
Thanks very much for your answer. Actually I read about this yesterday prior to end of work. 
I didn't try it. Will monday though. If it works (I expect it will) I'll give you credit for the answer. 
For those who are interested please see the two links below:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html_form_submit.asp?text=test%2FOfSlash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
The thing is that when using a field in a subform which is filled with a test "company/companytype" (in the case slash "/" is included in the text string) the prompt returns "CN=company/O=companytype".
Problem solved by stripping first three characters and replace "/O=" with "/".
Thanks for your answers.
Lars